# Casting varchar to int in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column airline_id which is varchar in the table route, now I want to copy that value into the column airline_id_int which has the type int. I can't get the syntax right though..

This is what I have:

```
UPDATE route SET airline_id_int = CAST(airline_id, int);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use the **AS** keyword for **CAST**.

```
update route set airline_id_int = cast(airline_id AS UNSIGNED)
```

You can use

```
update route set airline_id_int = cast(airline_id AS SIGNED)
```

as well.

Comment: you can't cast directly to int in mysql

Comment: Excellent! I found some non numeric values in my column, more specifically "\N". How would I turn all the "\N" into 0 and the rest casted as above?

Comment: You can use REPLACE function for the same. For example, if the column text is "A\NISHV\NARYA", use REPLACE('A\NISHV\NARYA','\N','0')

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
update route set airline_id_int = cast(airline_id AS UNSIGNED);
```

It's not possible to cast directly to `int`.
If you need signed int, replace `UNSIGNED` with `SIGNED`.

Answer (score 1):

```
update route set airline_id_int = cast(airline_id as signed);
```

or

```
update route set airline_id_int = cast(airline_id as unsigned);
```

if it can be negative

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update route set airline_id_int = CONVERT(airline_id, UNSIGNED);
update route set airline_id_int = CONVERT(airline_id, SIGNED);
```